# Qual a melhor forma de fazer uma tarefa muito grande e repetitiva?

Tags: python, desempenho, áudio

Eu preciso pegar a duração de 18000+ áudios, usando a biblioteca `audioread` para cada áudio demora certa de 300ms, ou seja, pelo menos 25~30 minutos de processando.

Usando um sistema de `Queue` e `Process`, usando todos os núcleos disponíveis do meu processador, eu consigo diminuir a media de processamento de cada áudio para 70ms, mas isso ainda vai levar 21 minutos, como eu posso melhorar isso ? Eu gostaria de conseguir ler todos os áudios em pelo menos 5 minutos, lembrando que eu não tenho concorrência na maquina, ela vai rodar só meu software, então posso consumir todos os recursos.

Código para ler a duração:

```
def get_duration(q, au):
    while not q.empty():
        index = q.get()
        with audioread.audio_open(au[index]['absolute_path']) as f:
            au[index]['duration'] = f.duration * 1000
```

Código que cria os Processos:

```
for i in range(os.cpu_count()):
    pr = Process(target=get_duration, args=(queue, audios, ))
    pr.daemon = True
    pr.start()
```

No meu código só tem uma `Queue` com alguns `Process`, e uso o `Manager` para editar os objetos.

Comment: Arruma a identação do segundo loop, pfv

Comment: @Lucas Corrigido.

Comment: Dê uma olhada na biblioteca Threading https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html